# Clean cumulative sum alongside grouped sum

Tags: psql

I am working in `PostgreSQL 9.6.6`

For the sake of reproducibility, I'll use `create tempory table` to create a "constant" table to play with:

```
create temporary table test_table as 
    select * from 
            (values 
                ('2018-01-01', 2),
                ('2018-01-01', 3),
                ('2018-02-01',  1),
                ('2018-02-01', 2))
            as t (month, count)
```

A `select * from test_table` returns the following:

```
   month    | count 
------------+-------
 2018-01-01 |     2
 2018-01-01 |     3
 2018-02-01 |     1
 2018-02-01 |     2
```

The desired output is the following:

```
   month    | sum | cumulative_sum 
------------+-----+----------------
 2018-01-01 |   5 |              5
 2018-02-01 |   3 |              8
```

In other words, the values have been summed, grouping by month, and then the cumulative sum is displayed in another column.

The issue is that the only way I know to achieve this is somewhat convoluted.  The grouped sum must be computed first, (as with a sub select or `with` statement), and then the running tally is computed with a select statement against that table, as so:

```
with sums as 
    (select month,
        sum(count) as sum
    from test_table
    group by 1)
select month,
    sum,
    sum(sum) over (order by month) as cumulative_sum
from sums
```

What I *wish* could work would be something more like...

```
select month,
    sum(count) as sum,
    sum(count) over (order by month) as cumulative_sum
from test_table
group by 1
```

But this returns

```
ERROR:  column "test_table.count" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 3:    sum(count) over (order by month) as cumulative_sum
```

No amount of fussing with the `group by` clause seems to satisfy PSQL.

**TL,DR**: is there a way in PSQL to compute both a sum over groups and the cumulative sum over groups using just a single `select` statement?  More generally, is there a "preferred" way to accomplish this, beyond the method I use in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch to use `SUM` as an analytic function was on the right track, but you need to analytic sum the aggregate sum:

```
SELECT month,
    SUM(count) as sum,
    SUM(SUM(count)) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS cumulative_sum
FROM test_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

As to why this works, the analytic functions are applied after the `GROUP BY` clause has happened.  So the aggregate sum in fact is available when we go take the rolling sum.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for!  Thank you very much, Tim!  You've just drastically improved the readability of all my BI queries

Comment: You're too prompt: accept answer is still frozen, but I'll hit it in 2 minutes :)